# C# Enum Flags - roles edit, view, admin

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators, bitflags

I define my roles like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Roles : byte
{        
    View = 1,       
    Edit = 2,    
    Admin = (View | Edit)
}
```

- View role, can view only
- Edit can view and edit only
- Admin can do Admin stuff, edit and view

Am I doing something wrong in defining my Enum?

Comment: What's the problem you are having?

Comment: Do you have an actual issue? Other than the fact that `Admin` is not the same as  combining `Edit` and `View`?

Comment: I want to differentiate the Admin from Edit and I don't know how. Because Admin now is View | Edit, But Edit is also Edit | View so i'm kinda confused about this.

Comment: Like I said, `Admin` is it's own role, it is not the sum of `View` and `Edit` so you can't do this.

Comment: So, How can I compare this bit mask to a Role value?

Comment: let's say if user is Admin, he can do everything ...

Comment: "Edit is also Edit | View" - not in your definition, "Admin" has an integer value of 3 or 11 as a bit mask,  "View" has an integer value of 1 and a bit mask of 01, and "Edit" has an integer value of 2 and a bit mask of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks fine, though for flags you must remember you cannot increment by ones (1, 2, 3, 4) - it must be done like: 1, 2, 4, 8.

Using your enum definition:

```
[Flags]
public enum Roles : byte
{
    View = 1,
    Edit = 2,
    Admin = (View | Edit) // Good for code readability - and if the values change
}
```

You can see that you can detect individual flags set like this (even specifically the Admin one).

```
Roles role = Roles.Admin;
bool canView = ((role & Roles.View) == Roles.View);
bool canEdit = ((role & Roles.Edit) == Roles.Edit);
bool isAdmin = (role == Roles.Admin);
```

You can see this work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0pm4jW

I also like this kind of definition for readability (and not having to calculate the math if I want to add one later).

```
[Flags]
public enum Roles : byte
{
    View   = 1 << 0, // 1
    Edit   = 1 << 1, // 2
    Delete = 1 << 2, // 4
    Share  = 1 << 3, // 8
    Admin = (View | Edit | Delete | Share)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The admin definition is valid only in case you want to separate roles and use Admin to group them. Just rewrite your enum into english:

```
View is equal View and nothing more
Edit is equal Edit and nothing more
Admin is equal Admin or Edit or View
```

If you want roles fallback (like Admin -> Edit -> View) you have to consider it as unique roles (even admin) and use order to specify how the role is important:

```
public enum Roles // note there is no flag attribute
{        
    View = 1,       
    Edit = 2,    
    Admin = 3
}
```

how to test role? just create simple function:

```
bool isInRole(Roles currentRole, Roles expectedRole)
{
    return currentRole >= expectedRole;
}

isInRole(Roles.Admin, Roles.Admin); // true
isInRole(Roles.Edit, Roles.Admin); // false
isInRole(Roles.Edit, Roles.Edit); // true
isInRole(Roles.Edit, Roles.View); // true
```